# How to show Google maps and leaflet draw polygons in a same layer?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am able to display marker & geojson polygons using leaflet and google maps.but map and polygons are coming in different layers this is not looking good when you zoom in,zoom out or while dragging .How can I display them in a same layer? here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lFUiS6j2kHtL4lGpH9J9?p=preview)!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  .leaflet-google-layer {
    z-index: 0 !important;
  }  
  .leaflet-map-pane {
    z-index: 100;
  }
</style>

<head>
  <title>Leaflet Draw</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/lib/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.css" />

  <!--[if lte IE 8]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.ie.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.draw.ie.css" />
    <![endif]-->

  <script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.25"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div id="map" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

      var map = new L.Map('map', {
        center: new L.LatLng(-37.7772, 175.2756),
        zoom: 9
      });
      var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
      map.addLayer(googleLayer);

      var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
      map.addLayer(drawnItems);

      var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
          position: 'topleft',
          polygon: {
            title: 'Draw a sexy polygon!',
            allowIntersection: false,
            drawError: {
              color: '#b00b00',
              timeout: 1000
            },
            shapeOptions: {
              color: '#bada55'
            },
            showArea: true
          },
          polyline: {
            metric: false
          },
          circle: {
            shapeOptions: {
              color: '#662d91'
            }
          }
        },
        edit: {
          featureGroup: drawnItems
        }
      });


      map.addControl(drawControl);
      map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
        var type = e.layerType,
          layer = e.layer;

        if (type === 'marker') {
          layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
        }

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        var geoPoints = layer.toGeoJSON();
        console.log(geoPoints);
      });



      map.on('draw:edited', function(e) {
        var layers = e.layers;
        layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
          var geoPoints = layer.toGeoJSON();
          console.log(geoPoints);
        });
      });

      map.on('draw:deleted', function(e) {
        var layers = e.layers;
        layers.eachLayer(function(layer) {
          var geoPoints = layer.toGeoJSON();
          console.log(geoPoints);
        });
      });



      L.geoJson($scope.geojsonFeatures, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      });



      $scope.geojsonFeatures = {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              175.2756, -37.7772
            ]
          }
        }, {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                [
                  175.27364730834958, -37.77322501372662
                ],
                [
                  175.27849674224854, -37.776617142149554
                ],
                [
                  175.28351783752439, -37.784486280685925
                ],
                [
                  175.28879642486572, -37.781365860467126
                ],
                [
                  175.2824878692627, -37.7707486617024
                ],
                [
                  175.27364730834958, -37.77322501372662
                ]
              ]
            ]
          }
        }]
      };
      console.log($scope.geojsonFeatures);
      L.geoJson($scope.geojsonFeatures, {
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      });




      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be done. The current implementations of Leaflet plugins for displaying Google maps imply creating a GMaps instance, and **trying** to keep its view (center and zoom) in sync with Leaflet's view.

This is hackish but currently the only way to do this - and has the obvious disadvantage of not syncing up the pan and zoom transitions (which use different inertia, speed curves and interpolation in both libraries).

---

Edit: I just created the [GoogleMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant) Leaflet plugin a couple days ago, which should help with this whole affair.